# how to convert GifImageView to Bitmap?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have a Gif running in my app. when I press the stop button, the Gif stops. What I wanted to do is to convert the stopped Gif to a bitmap so that I can compare it to another image which is also converted to a bitmap.
My code doesn't seem to work.

I'm using this library

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
android:id="@+id/img_1"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/gif_1"

/>
```

and this is my onClickListener

```
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(counter%2==0){


                image.setFreezesAnimation(true);
                ((GifDrawable)image.getBackground()).stop();

                image.buildDrawingCache();



                Bitmap b2 = image.getDrawingCache();

                Drawable d1 = getDrawable(R.drawable.lvl_1);
                Bitmap b1 = ((BitmapDrawable)d1).getBitmap();



                if(b1.sameAs(b2))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this,"GOOD JOB!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(NextActivity.this,"ALMOST!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                counter++;


            }
            else{
                image.setFreezesAnimation(false);

                ((GifDrawable)image.getBackground()).start();
                counter++;


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: is `image.getDrawingCache();` returning null?

Comment: i got image.buildDrawingCache(). If it is null is should crash.

Comment: why did you say it might return null? Maybe I could realize something.

Comment: Then what do you mean by code doesn't seem to work? Are you getting the "ALMOST" toast?

Comment: Are you setting `image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` before calling `image.getDrawingCache();` ?

Comment: hmmmm. I guess the image is indeed null. I tried comparing the same bitmap from the drawable just to test the condition. and it did. I tried your suggestion but it is still "null" I guess.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 image.setFreezesAnimation(true);
 ((GifDrawable) image.getDrawable()).stop();
 image.buildDrawingCache();
 Bitmap b2 = image.getDrawingCache();

 Drawable d1 = getDrawable(R.drawable.lvl_1);
 Bitmap b1 = ((BitmapDrawable)d1).getBitmap();
    //...rest of the code
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work. I know there's always a solution to a problem. I'll try to search more.

Comment: whaaaaaatttt?? really? I would appreciate if you could share your code so that I could test it and I'll debug my code. please.

Comment: I could give you the gif file and you could test it if you want.

Comment: What I tried is in the answer. For me, `b2` was not null.

Comment: How will I know if it is not null?

Comment: `if(b2 == null){System.out.println("null"); } else { System.out.println("not null")}`